# Did something go wrong if I checkout a branch I never worked on and there are a number of outgoing commits?

Tags: git

We have a development branch and we usually only do our development in feature branches. Sometimes - if work on the issue takes longer than expected, I would merge the development branch into the feature branch.

When I checkout the development branch, I see a number of available fetches. OK. But I also see a number of outgoing commits - as if I had uncommitted changes in my local development branch. I am sure however that I never committed to that branch and I also checked if any of my upstreams were set to that origin/development.

Some - but not all - of those outgoing commits are already present on the remote development branch. My solution was to stop tracking origin/development, rename the local development branch and check out development again.

My question is: how does this happen? Is this related to commits that were removed from origin/development but are still in my local branch?

Comment: if you never worked on that branch then u should sync this branch with remote.
let say you want to syn development branch.
`git fetch origin`
`git checkout development`
`git reset --hard origin/development`
after above steps you doesn't get un expected behavior

Comment: @rahul OK, that looks like a clean way to circumvent the problem, but what may be the actual reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *branch name* like `development` is really just a clever way of holding a raw commit hash ID.  You have your Git *create* these names for you, so as to remember a hash ID.  You do this using `git checkout` or `git branch`.

A *remote-tracking name* like `origin/development` is, similarly, a clever way of holding a raw commit hash ID.  You don't explicitly ask your Git to create these.  Instead, your Git, looking at your repository, creates these when your Git calls up some *other* Git—the one that you call `origin`—and asks that other Git about *its* repository.  That Git says things like: *I have a `development` that names commit `a123456...` and a `master` that names commit `b987654...`*.  At this point, your Git creates or updates your `origin/development`, setting it to `a123456...`, and your `origin/master`, setting it to `b987654...`.

Hence, your `origin/*` names are your Git's way of remembering *their* Git's *branch* names, the last time your Git synced up with their Git.  And—perhaps most important—all of these names are just clever ways of remembering *commit hash IDs*, with each name remembering exactly *one* hash ID.

#### The key to understanding all of this is some graph theory

In Git, each commit records its *parent* commit's hash ID.  This parent hash ID records which commit is the one that comes *before* this commit.  In some cases—for merge commits—a commit records more than one parent hash ID, with the *first* of these hash IDs being "the commit that comes before", and in at least one special case for the very *first* commit, a commit has *no* parent.  (This parentless or *root* commit has to be able to exist, because the first commit someone makes can't have an earlier commit.)

Whenever Git looks at your commits, it does so by starting with some hash ID, usually derived from a branch name like `master`.  We say that this hash ID represents the *tip* commit of that branch.  Because the commit records its parent, Git can follow the chain backwards.  The name `master` locates some commit with hash `H`; but `H` has some parent `G`:

```
... <--G  <--H   <---master
```

and of course `G` has some parent `F`, which has some parent `E`, and so on:

```
...--E--F--G--H   <-- master
```

To add a *new* commit to a branch, Git simply writes out the new commit—the new snapshot—with the *old* tip as its parent, so that our new commit `I` points back to `H`:

```
...--E--F--G--H--I
```

—and then rewrites the name `master` to contain the hash ID of commit `I`:

```
...--E--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

This is why any name—whether it's your own branch name like `master`, or a remote-tracking name like `origin/master`—need only hold *one* hash ID.  It's the *commits themselves* that form the graph.  Git just needs a starting point (perhaps it would be better to call it an "ending point", but Git always works backwards) to get into the graph and be able to follow the backwards chains of commits.

#### What you're encountering

You now say:

> When I checkout the development branch ...

If you don't have a `development` yet, and you ask Git to check out your existing name `development`, your Git has a problem: it doesn't *have* a `development` to check out.  What your Git does at this point is to *create* your `development`, pointing to the *same* commit as your `origin/development`, and to set your `development`'s upstream to `origin/development`.  Note that at this point, the two names will point to the *same* commit.

If you *do* have a `development`, and you ask your Git to checkout your existing `development`, your Git checks out whichever commit hash ID is stored under your existing name `development`.  That's whatever is left over from earlier.

> ... I see a number of available fetches. OK. But I also see a number of outgoing commits - as if I had uncommitted changes in my local development branch.

There's a terminology problem here.  I am guessing that what you mean is that your Git prints a message along these lines:

```
Your branch and 'origin/development' have diverged,
and have 3 and 5 different commits each.
```

The first number is the number of commits that are *reachable* from your branch name (`development`) that are not reachable from the name `origin/development`.  The second number is the number of commits reachable from the name `origin/development` that are not reachable from your branch name.  That is, the graph picture looks like this now:

```
          A--B--C   <-- development
         /
...--o--*
         \
          D--E--F--G--H   <-- origin/development
```

You have three commits (`A-B-C`) that are reachable from your `development` that are not reachable from `origin/development`.  You have five that are reachable from `origin/development` that are not reachable from `development`.  Remember, Git works *backwards*—it starts at the tip (`C`) and moves only towards the past.

`D-E-F-G-H` are not "available fetches" (you already have the commits, you do not have to fetch them), nor are `A-B-C` necessarily *outgoing commits*.  They are just *reachable from* your `development`.

> I am sure however that I never committed to that branch ...

If you did not add `A-B-C` to your `development` yourself, they must have existed when you first *created* the name `development`.  For instance, suppose that some time in the past, your `origin/development` named commit `C`:

```
...--o--*--A--B--C   <-- origin/development
```

At this time, if you run `git checkout development` and you don't *have* `development`, your Git *creates* your own `development`, pointing to commit `C`:

```
...--o--*--A--B--C   <-- origin/development, development (HEAD)
```

(Git attaches the name `HEAD` to whichever branch you have checked out, so that it knows you're on `development` now rather than `master`.)

Now, someone, or several someones, is in control of the Git repository you call `origin`.  Suppose someone, for some reason, decides to *remove* commits `A-B-C` from their `development`:

```
          A--B--C   [cast aside, on origin]
         /
...--o--*   <-- [development on origin]
```

You then run `git fetch`.  Your Git will update your `origin/development` so that it, too, *lacks* the `A-B-C` chain—but in your own repository, your branch name `development` exists now, so it *continues* to point to commit `C`:

```
          A--B--C   <-- development (HEAD)
         /
...--o--*   <-- origin/development
```

You are now "three commits ahead".  They are not commits you *made*, but you *had* them, and your Git *has not thrown them away; it will not do so without some sort of instruction from you*.

You can detect that this has occurred because when you run `git fetch` it will tell you.  For instance, here is the output from `git fetch` on my Git repository for Git, this morning:

> ```
>    e3331758f1..b7bd9486b0  master     -> origin/master
>    fc54c1af3e..53f9a3e157  maint      -> origin/maint
>    fac676dfb9..5c9ce644c3  next       -> origin/next
>  + 5fc3b55b9a...1aaaa8cf15 pu         -> origin/pu  (forced update)
>    be70464a91..f59de5ad04  todo       -> origin/todo
> ```

Note the plus sign, the three dots, and the words "forced update" in front of the update to my `origin/pu`.  The Git repository for Git is one where all users have agreed that the "pickup" branch (origin/pu) can be rewound and rewritten like this.  If I make my own `pu` corresponding to `origin/pu`, I must be prepared to remove commits.

#### It's generally a bad idea to remove commits like this

If users are not prepared to have commits vanish from their remote-tracking names, those users are likely to keep *re-introducing* the commits.  For instance, given the retraction above to remove `A-B-C`, if I were to run:

```
git push origin development
```

I would send `A-B-C` right back to `origin` and suggest that they make their `development` point to commit `C`.  Right now, that would probably be fine with them: they'd put those commits right back on.

If they have added the `D-E-F-G-H` chain since then, I'd be encouraged (by my own Git) to merge my `C` with my `H`, giving me:

```
          A--B--C---------I   <-- development (HEAD)
         /               /
...--o--*               /
         \             /
          D--E--F--G--H   <-- origin/development
```

and I could again `git push origin development` to add the `A-B-C-I` chain, which they would accept.

If I know what happened, and agree that `A-B-C` should be removed, I can use `git reset --hard origin/development` after checking out my `development`, or I can *delete* my branch name `development` and then use `git checkout development` to create a *new* `development` pointing to commit `H`, giving me:

```
          A--B--C   [abandoned - will be removed by git gc in about a month]
         /
...--o--*--D--E--F--G--H   <-- development (HEAD), origin/development
```

Git is built to *add* commits to chains.  It's much more reluctant to *remove* them.  Figure out who is removing commits and why, and make sure that they understand that this makes work for every other user.  Make sure that you and all the other users agree that this is going to happen, and only *then* should they be removing commits like this.  Then you all need to watch out for forced updates on those remote-tracking names.

Comment: You really did the work. Great explanation, I am sure this is exactly what's happening and I learned some things, e.g.what "reachable" commits are. I am using Visual Studio which offers spartan git support, I did not notice any "branch has diverged" messages. I guess I should not be using VS but the command line or at least Git Extensions.